# More than one redirect with trailing slash in secure non-www url

Tags: magento2, nginx

There is more than one redirect with trailing slash in secure non-www url. This doesn’t happen on homepage url like https://example.com. As you can see from below a secure non-www url is forwarded to a url with trailing slash and then again forwarded to one with no slash. I am running magento 2.3.3, Nginx, PHP 7.3 on centos 7. Below is my nginx conf file.  Below is the server nginx conf file. Any clue would be highly appreciated.

```
https://example.com/mens-wear
https://www.example.com/mens-wear/
https://www.example.com/mens-wear

server {
    listen      443 ssl http2;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1.2  TLSv1.3;
    root        /home/example/web/example.com/public_html/pub;
    index       index.php;
    autoindex   off;
    charset     UTF-8;
    error_page  404 403 = /errors/404.php;
    add_header  "X-UA-Compatible" "IE=Edge";

    ssl_certificate      /home/example/conf/web/ssl.example.com.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  /home/example/conf/web/ssl.example.com.key;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/domains/example.com.log combined;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/domains/example.com.bytes bytes;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/domains/example.com.error.log error;

    # PHP entry point for setup application
    location ~* ^/setup($|/) {
        root /home/example/web/example.com/public_html;

        location ~ ^/setup/index.php {
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9002;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ~ ^/setup/(?!pub/). {
            deny all;
        }

        location ~ ^/setup/pub/ {
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        }
    }

    # PHP entry point for update application
    location ~* ^/update($|/) {
        root /home/example/web/example.com/public_html;

        location ~ ^/update/index.php {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/update/index.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9002;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
            include        /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }

        # Deny everything but index.php
        location ~ ^/update/(?!pub/). {
            deny all;
        }

        location ~ ^/update/pub/ {
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        }
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location /pub/ {
        location ~ ^/pub/media/(downloadable|customer|import|theme_customization/.*\.xml) {
            deny all;
        }

        alias /home/example/web/example.com/public_html/pub/;
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }

    location /static/ {
        # Uncomment the following line in production mode
        # expires max;

    # Remove signature of the static files that is used to overcome the browser cache
        location ~ ^/static/version {
            rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static/$2 last;
        }

        location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2|json)$ {
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
include /etc/nginx/magento2-cors.conf;           
        expires +1y;

    if (!-f $request_filename) {
                rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
            }
        }

        location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
            add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
include /etc/nginx/magento2-cors.conf;           
        expires    off;

    if (!-f $request_filename) {
                rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
            }
        }

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
        }

        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
include /etc/nginx/magento2-cors.conf;
    }

    location /media/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php?$args;

        location ~ ^/media/theme_customization/.*\.xml {
            deny all;
        }

        location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
include /etc/nginx/magento2-cors.conf;
            expires +1y;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php?$args;
        }

        location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
            add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
include /etc/nginx/magento2-cors.conf;
            expires    off;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php?$args;
        }

        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
include /etc/nginx/magento2-cors.conf;    
    }

    location /media/customer/ {
        deny all;
    }

    location /media/downloadable/ {
        deny all;
    }

    location /media/import/ {
        deny all;
    }

    location /errors/ {
        location ~* \.xml$ {
            deny all;
        }
    }

    # PHP entry point for main application
    location ~ (index|get|static|report|404|503|info)\.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;

        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9002;
        fastcgi_buffers 1024 4k;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;

        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_min_length 1100;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types
        text/plain
        text/css
        text/js
        text/xml
        text/javascript
        application/javascript
        application/x-javascript
        application/json
        application/xml
        application/xml+rss
        image/svg+xml;
    gzip_vary on;

    # Banned locations (only reached if the earlier PHP entry point regexes don't match)
    location ~* (\.php$|\.htaccess$|\.git) {
        deny all;
    }

    location /vstats/ {
        alias   /home/example/web/example.com/stats/;
        include /home/example/conf/web/example.com.auth*;
    }

    include     /etc/nginx/conf.d/phpmyadmin.inc*;
    include     /etc/nginx/conf.d/phppgadmin.inc*;
    include     /etc/nginx/conf.d/webmail.inc*;

    include     /home/example/conf/web/snginx.example.com.conf*;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

How are you currently handling the redirect? I assume since you only have the 1 Nginx server block for the site and letting Magento handle it the redirect using the Base Url?

Adding a server block like so and removing the `example.com` server name from the existing block should handle redirecting with the exact same request URI (not appending /).

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Opting for using Nginx to handle the redirect would increase performance + server load too.

Comment: This is my non-ssl nginx conf.  server {
    listen      80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

Comment: Does https request go through the above conf?

Comment: If you want the one directive to listen to both https/http you can use 2 listen directives (updated answer)

Comment: I tried this. Still the secure non-www url goes through more than one redirect.